# SoundPlayer: How to select Output device?

Tags: c#, .net, audio

How can I select the output device for my application? I'm using the [`SoundPlayer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.aspx) class to play wav files.

Comment: It always plays back on the default WAV output device.  Ask at superuser.com or a manufacturer's forum if you have unusual hardware.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should drop SoundPlayer usage for something like this (and for anything else aside of playing common system sounds). I suggest you go and use [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com), it allows what you are looking for, and more.

Answer (score 1):

I needed same functionality. Here is my solution using [NAudio](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=naudio) (same as Neverbirth suggested)

To list all devices:

```
for (int n = -1; n < WaveOut.DeviceCount; n++)
{
    var caps = WaveOut.GetCapabilities(n);
    Console.WriteLine($"{n}: {caps.ProductName}");
}
```

Play wave file:

```
WaveFileReader wav = new WaveFileReader("somefile.wav");
var output = new WaveOutEvent { DeviceNumber = 0 };
output.Init(wav);
output.Play();
```

Don't forget to cleanup ressources:

```
wav.Dispose();
output.Dispose();
```

More information [here](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/Docs/EnumerateOutputDevices.md) and [here](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/wiki/Playing-an-Audio-File)

Comment: Look ok... But why are you iterating starting at -1 ?
Also you shouldn't use .Dispose(). Use "using".

Comment: -1 : take a look at official [documentation](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/Docs/EnumerateOutputDevices.md#wavein-or-waveinevent), that is how it's done.
Dispose : you might want to have wav file playing, continue executing code, and only dispose later (eg : user press stop button or wave is complete). If you put code in a using as soon as you leave using clause wav will be stopped. The using clause is OK if you want to block and wait until the wav is fully played.